# Open R project in RStudio programmatically?

Tags: r, rstudio

In a similar way to how `file.edit('foo.R')` opens a file for editing in RStudio, is there a way to open an R project if you know the location of its `.Rproj` file?

Comment: What operating system are you on?

Comment: Windows 8.1, thanks!

Comment: Perhaps using `system`?

Answer (score 2):

Have at look at function `openProject()` in package `rstudioapi`