# Programmatically load file into Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm developing R code whose output is an R script, is it possible to automatically load the generated file in a `RStudio` tab?

So far I've checked the `rstudioapi`, but I don't find any suitable function.

I've already tried:

```
file.show(stringr::str_c(name,".r"))
```

but file.show open the file using an external editor.

Comment: is [file.edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37724057/open-r-project-in-rstudio-programmatically) what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `source("path/to/script.R")` to run an R script, and load all the data/variables into the global R environment

In order to just open the file in RStudio, without running it, you can use `rstudioapi::navigateToFile("path/to/file.R")`

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response!, do you know if is it possible to just load the file?, I want the user can review the script before source it.

Comment: Good question, I've edited my answer to show how to just open the file